# MVC PHP - Should I use controller for each sub-panel in my website

Tags: php, model-view-controller

In my website, different pages like add new customers, customers list, firm or company panel.
should I call the controller for each panel or I should use the ajax for partial refresh.

Please suggest me what should I use, which is the best way for better application.

Comment: depends on capabilities of chosen framework.

Comment: What framework are you using?

Comment: I am using my own MVC framework..

Answer (score 0):

Ajax is always a better option, because it keeps the rest of your page intact, which is visually much more desirable. However, there must be enough error checking both on client and server side to ensure the validity and correctness of data.

The best way is to create layered structure like:
UI -> Controller -> Service -> Repository (Database Queries).
You can use Ajax to call functions in your **Controllers** which in turn invoke **Service** layer to solve business logic and get or set any data by calling the **Repositories**.

This approach is helpful especially when you need to create both **Public** as well as **Admin** interfaces of your website which appears to be necessary in your case.